# Get Document Directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a little singleplayer cheat for a game and am planning on making it public, I have written the API and it all works well but I want to save the data that the user enters to a .ini file so that they will only have to log in one time unless their credentials change. I have done this and it works with a relative path `C:\Users\Name\Documents\Cheat\Authorise.ini` Although When check the result, it doesn't seem to save nor read the data in the file.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to get the Documents Directory.

Function:

```
std::string authFile = "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents\\Cheats\\Authorise.ini";
std::string username = GUI::Files::ReadStringFromIni(authFile, "Login", "Username");
std::string password = GUI::Files::ReadStringFromIni(authFile, "Login", "Password");`
```

Comment: You have at least to replace `%USERNAME%` from the environment variables.

Comment: The proper way to get the user's Documents folder (or any other folder) is using [ShGetKnownFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath)

Comment: `%USERNAME%` works in a shell that replaces the variables by their values, but not for functions from the Windows APIs.

Comment: In my opinion "I know this has been asked 100 times before, but I..." is one of the worst introductions you could come up with. It suggests that you you are just too lazy to search the identical questions and their answers and expect us to waste our time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows, you should use the Windows API call available for this very purpose in `<ShlObj.h>` called `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.  Note that you had best use a `std::wstring` instead for this purpose, since there is no variant of `SHGetKnownFolderPath` that accepts an MBCS or ANSI string. Also, this will get you the entire path to the user's profile directory, not just the username.

```
PWSTR path;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &path);
std::wstring strpath(path);
CoTaskMemFree(path);
```

Also, once you're done with `path`, free it with `CoTaskMemFree`.

Comment: @KieronTateL %userprofile% is as wrong as %username%. Don't use either.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, could you maybe give me usage of it with the code `std::string authFile = "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents\\Cheats\\Authorise.ini";
std::string username = GUI::Files::ReadStringFromIni(authFile, "Login", "Username");
std::string password = GUI::Files::ReadStringFromIni(authFile, "Login", "Password");`

Comment: @KieronTate It would appear that Werner Henze's comment on your question is spot-on

Comment: @GovindParmar your code example gets the path to the user's root profile directory, not to the user's documents folder, which may not even be located under the profile. You need to use `FOLDERID_Documents` instead of `FOLDERID_Profile`.

Comment: @GovindParmar don't forget error handing, too. `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` can fail, and `std::wstring` can raise an allcoation failure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One could argue that a person developing a cheat engine for Windows should be aware of how and when to handle allocation and COM errors

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of Windows store user profiles in different locations, and even the default name of the `Documents` folder can differ. In fact, the name and  location of the user's `Documents` folder is fully customizable by the user, and may not even be located under the user's profile at all.  So, you should not assume the `Documents` folder is always located at `C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents`.

The best way to get the *correct* path to a user's `Documents` folder on all versions of Windows is to simply *ask Windows itself*. Use [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) (pre-Vista) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) (Vista+) for that, eg:

```
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

std::string GetDocumentsFolder()
{
    std::string path;

    char szPath[MAX_PATH+1] = {};
    if (SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath) == S_OK)
        path = PathAddBackslashA(szPath);

    /*
    PWSTR pPath = NULL;
    if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &pPath) == S_OK)
    {
        int wlen = lstrlenW(pPath);
        int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pPath, wlen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            path.resize(len+1);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pPath, wlen, &path[0], len, NULL, NULL);
            path[len] = '\\';
        }
        CoTaskMemFree(pPath);
    }
    */

    return path;
}

std::string GetAuthFilePath()
{
    std::string path = GetDocumentsFolder();
    if (!path.empty())
        path += "Cheats\\Authorise.ini";
    return path;    
}

std::string authFile = GetAuthFilePath();
...
```